# Float is showing an unpredictable behaviour ? The content of the hidden block [beneath the floating block] came outside of it?

Tags: css-float

Navy block is not floating hence it went under, beneath the orange block (as float works in 3d), That i understood,But the content of navy block "navy", has came outside in the green block why is that, it should have also been in the hidden block itself ???

Thanks in advance, But this doubt is stuck in my head & because of it i am not able to move forward in my learning process.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Float Doubt</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .box{
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      color: black;
      font-size: 22px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 100px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .div1{
      background-color: orange;
      float: left;
    }
    .div2{
      background-color: red;
      float: left;
    }
    .div3{       
      background-color: navy;
      color: white;
    }
    .div4{
      background-color: green;
      float: left;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="div1 box">orange</div>
  <div class="div2 box">red</div>
  <div class="div3 box">navy</div>
  <div class="div4 box">green</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the floats whenever you are using left or right floats on div blocks

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Float Doubt</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .box{
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      color: black;
      font-size: 22px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 100px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .div1{
      background-color: orange;
      float: left;
    }
    .div2{
      background-color: red;
      float: left;
    }
    .div3{       
      background-color: navy;
      color: white;
    }
    .div4{
      background-color: green;
      float: left;
    }
    .clear{
      clear:left;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div1 box">orange</div>
    <div class="div2 box">red</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="div3 box">navy</div>
    <div class="div4 box">green</div>
</body>
</html>
```